# Send raw JSON and file in the same web api 2 endpoint

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api

I was wondering whether it is possible to send a file (which I only want ".pdf", ".jpg" or ".png") along with raw JSON.
All my endpoints so far send raw JSON (which I'm testing via Postman as the frontend does not exist yet), the intention is that the sending of form data will be sent using Angular Js. I don't know Angular Js yet, so I can't imagine how this will work.

The signature of the endpoint in question looks like this:

```
[Route("Post")]
    [CustomAuthorize(Roles = "User, Admin")]
    [ValidateJWT]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(HttpRequestMessage request, SalesOrderViewModel orderData)
```

The view model is just a c# class with loads of string properties that the model binder converts from JSON.

I would like to know whether sending raw JSON and a file that the user will select is possible in the same endpoint with Web API 2.
Is it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't direct with a post as aplication/json, still you can do it with multiple form fields (as form data), file + data, where the value of data can be a JSON.

I'm not recommending this method but does the trick:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
        {
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            //load in a memory stream or in azure blob storage
            var uploadFolder = "~/App_Data/FileUploads"; // to demonstrate the upload so please don't comment about where I'm saving the file, don't recommend this under no circumstance
            var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(uploadFolder);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(root);
            var provider =  new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
            var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            if (result.FileData.FirstOrDefault() == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("No import file was attached");
            }

            var uploadedFileInfo = new FileInfo(result.FileData.First().LocalFileName);

            var model = result.FormData["model"];

            if (model == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Model is missing");
            }

            var parameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Coords>(model);

            var byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(uploadedFileInfo.FullName);
           //..process the bytes
           //..process json passed in headers
}
```

And the model:

```
public class Coords
    {
        public Cord[] cords { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cord
    {
        public int x { get; set; }
        public object y { get; set; }
    }
```

Postman call:

[image]

Comment: Any particular reason that why you don't recommend this approach (of sending file and data using Form Post).

Comment: Because above example is a hybrid approach, you have to deserilize form filed Model, see how serialized mode looks https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_serialize

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Just checked you don't have to use `IEnumerable<byte>`. Using `byte[]` works fine.

---

WebApi supports deserializing JSON array to `IEnumerable<T>`, so that you can receive bytes by declaring with `IEnumerable<byte>`.

The following example will show how to upload image:

```
public class ImageModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<byte> Bytes { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller. Writing image to disk:

```
private string WriteImage(byte[] arr)
{
    var filename = $@"images\{DateTime.Now.Ticks}.";

    using (var im = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(arr)))
    {
        ImageFormat frmt;
        if (ImageFormat.Png.Equals(im.RawFormat))
        {
            filename += "png";
            frmt = ImageFormat.Png;
        }
        else
        {
            filename += "jpg";
            frmt = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
        }
        string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") + filename;
        im.Save(path, frmt);
    }

    return $@"http:\\{Request.RequestUri.Host}\{filename}";
}
```

`HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/")` will give the internal path of server running. `Request.RequestUri.Host` returns the hostname.

```
public IHttpActionResult UploadImage(ImageModel model)
{
    var imgUrl = WriteImage(model.Bytes.ToArray());

    // Some code
}
```

In HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="imageFile"/>
```

Upload method for AngularJS:

```
$scope.upload = function () {

     var file = document.getElementById("imageFile").files[0];
     var r = new FileReader();
     r.onloadend = function (e) {


         var arr = Array.from(new Uint8Array(e.target.result));

         var uploadData = {
             Name: "Name of Image",
             Bytes: arr
         }
         console.log(uploadData);

         $http.post('api/Uploader/UploadImage', uploadData)
         .then(
         function (response) {
             console.log(response);
         },

         function (reason) {

             console.log(reason);
         })
     }
     r.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
 }
```